# want to use carrierwave for two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I want to save images for two different models. I am using carrierwave gem.

I have created as follows.

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avathar, AvatarUploader
 end
```

and

```
 class News < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, NewsUploader
 end
```

Uploaders:

```
 class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
 end
```

and

```
 class NewsUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
 end
```

It's working for User model. But it's not working for news model. Please help me to correct this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The information you are showing doesnt really help to answer your question...

### Have you created the migrate for this i.e.  like so but for posts? (AddAvatarToUsers)

```
class AddAvatarToNews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :news, :avatar, :string
  end
  def self.down
    remove_column :news, :avatar
  end
end
```

Then in your controller for news something like this...

```
def show
    @news = News.find(params[:id])
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:news_id])
end
```

Also what does it look like in your config/routes.rb are you stating the correct resources?

i.e.

```
 resources :users
 resources :news
 resources :photos
```